# How to consume kafka messages on prem on azure event hub?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, cloud, apache-kafka-streams, azure-eventhub

I want to consume kafka messages from on prem kafka service which is already in place ,in azure event hub.
I have topic and brokerlist .
I am not able to find where should I configure them on event hub to start receiving message.
Can anyone help me with steps?

I tried creating a event hub namespace and creating event.  What should be the next step?

Comment: You will need something like Kafka Connect to do the actual message sending, e.g. like this https://hevodata.com/learn/kafka-to-azure/

Answer (score 0):

> To consume Kafka messages from an on-premises Kafka service in Azure Event Hubs.

Thanks to `silent` for the comments.

You can use the Kafka protocol support in Event Hubs.

1. Create an Event Hub in Azure.
2. Configure the Kafka endpoint for the created Event Hub.

By creating a Kafka connection string for the Event Hub.
The connection string consists of `Event Hubs namespace` name, the `Event Hub name`, and the `Kafka endpoint`.  And you can find the Kafka endpoint in the on-premises Kafka service configuration.
[image]

[image]

Replace `{YOUR.EVENTHUBS.CONNECTION.STRING}` with the connection string for your Event Hubs namespace. For instructions on getting the connection string, see [Get an Event Hubs connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-get-connection-string). Here's an example configuration: `sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";`

References taken from [MSDoc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-kafka-connect-tutorial) and [MSDoc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/azure-event-hubs-kafka-overview#kafka-and-event-hub-conceptual-mapping).